# Dead link in Adobe Font CSS causing TestCafe to Hang?

Tags: css, fonts, adobe, testcafe, typekit

I have created a web project and embedded several Adobe fonts into it using the following

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/jwl3gmx.css">
</head>
```

The fonts load and display fine. Yet, I'm having problems with a css file that is imported by 'jwl3gmx.css'. Here's a clip from 'jwl3gmx.css':

```
@import url("https://p.typekit.net/p.css?s=1&k=jwl3gmx&ht=tk&f=42031.42035.42037.42039&a=20282561&app=typekit&e=css");
```

**This import statement always fails and causes my test suite to hang. Without the embedded Adobe fonts everything works perfectly**

I have created new web projects inside Adobe Fonts and they have this same issue.

[Screenshot of missing stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiJkE.png)

[Screenshot of missing stylesheet request info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX5CX.png)

Foremost how can I prevent/work around the failure? Second, why is this dead link in a production product?

Note: I am using TestCafe

Comment: Is it not an option to make a copy of the CSS file, remove the line and host the file in your web project?

Comment: I thought about hosting the fonts but not the css file directly. Could be a solution @radulfr